# How to pass XML path to check for sibling relation in lxml - python

Tags: python-3.x, xml, xpath

My python function to get the attribute value of an element

```
import lxml.etree as ET


def xml_get_attrib_value(filepath, xpath, attribute):
   it = ET.iterparse(filepath)
   for _, el in it:
      _, _, el.tag = el.tag.rpartition('}')
   root = it.root
   element = root.find(xpath)
   value = element.attrib[attribute]
   return value
```

Snippet of XML:

```
<outboundRelationship typeCode="SPRT">
    <priorityNumber value="1" />
    <relatedInvestigation classCode="INVSTG" moodCode="EVN">
        <code code="2" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.3.989.2.1.1.22" codeSystemVersion="2.0" />
```

I want to get the value of attribute, 'value' in <priorityNumber value="1" />

If I send an xpath that is straightforward, it works.
xpath: `.//outboundRelationship[@typeCode='SPRT']/priorityNumber`

However, if I want to check for the attribute of PriorityNumber with a condition that it should be a sibling of ‘relatedInvestigation’ which in turn has a child node, ‘code’ with specific attribute. I get error ‘`SyntaxError: invalid predicate`’

xpath: `.//outboundRelationship[@typeCode='SPRT'][relatedInvestigation/code[@code='2'][@codeSystem='2.16.840.1.113883.3.989.2.1.1.22']]/priorityNumber`

I tried using preceding:sibling in the xpath but that’s also not working.

How to send such xpath? Is there any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's xpath expression is correct but `find()` method has [limited xpath support](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lxml/+bug/1939925/comments/1). See also [FAQ](https://lxml.de/FAQ.html#what-are-the-findall-and-xpath-methods-on-element-tree).
Using `xpath()` instead of `find()` with same expression:

```
from lxml import etree
xtree = etree.parse('tmp.xml')

p = xtree.xpath(".//outboundRelationship[@typeCode='SPRT'][relatedInvestigation/code[@code='2'][@codeSystem='2.16.840.1.113883.3.989.2.1.1.22']]/priorityNumber")

print(p[0].attrib['value'])
```

Result

```
'1'
```

lxml version

```
etree.__version__
'4.9.3'
```

If namespaces are needed

```
ns = {'ns' : 'urn:hl7-org:v3'}
p = xtree.xpath(".//ns:outboundRelationship[@typeCode='SPRT'][ns:relatedInvestigation/ns:code[@code='2'][@codeSystem='2.16.840.1.113883.3.989.2.1.1.22']]/ns:priorityNumber",namespaces=ns)
```

Comment: Thank you! It works for a sample xml file that has only the snippet I mentioned. However, if I use the entire large xml (with namespace and many other nodes along with this snippet), it's not identifying the element. 'P' returns an empty list. Could this be due to namespace? What other things I should take into account? Is there a way I can share the actual entire xml file?

Comment: It could be due to namespaces, yes. You don't need to post the whole XML, just the relevant structure. You can try `//namespace::*` to list all namespaces in the file. If you use Linux this command could list namespaces: `xmllint --xpath '//namespace::*' file.xml | sort | uniq`

Comment: //namespace::* gives a very long list. 
Here are initial first few lines in the xml - <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MCCI_IN200100UV01 xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:mif="urn:hl7-org:v3/mif" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ITSVersion="XML_1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hl7-org:v3 http://eudravigilance.ema.europa.eu/XSD/multicacheschemas/MCCI_IN200100UV01.xsd" xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3">
  <!--N.1.2: Batch Number-->
  <id extension="US-DialogSolutions-Demo-PI011000-C1-20240223-184227" root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.989.2.1.3.22" />

Comment: Updated the answer. This is the namespace relevant to you most probably: `xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3"`

Comment: Thank you very much! Appreciate your help. Just wondering if there is a way to ignore the namespaces?

Comment: you could use the local-name making this on each element `*[local-name()="outboundRelationship"]` but it will give you a long and ugly expression. You can also accept the answer if you wish.